# Concatenation of INT columns warning: Type conversion in expression causes CardinalityEstimate warnings in execution plan

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan

Running on SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition.

I have a simple case where I am trying to take two INT columns and concatenate them into a single column called "NUMVER" separated by semicolons. Although I could refactor things in the app to do this differently, it would be interesting to know if its possible to not refactor and to change the syntax so that it won't  raise a "!" warning in the Execution Plan.

Details:

A table called 'DOCS' has columns, `NUM` and `VER`, both are `INT` plus a PK:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DOCS2](
    [DOCS_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [NUM] [int] NOT NULL,
    [VER] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DOCS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DOCS_ID] ASC)
)
GO
```

Some data:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.DOCS (NUM, VER) VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO dbo.DOCS (NUM, VER) VALUES (2,1);
```

I want to select NUM and VER into a single column NUMVER with a semicolon separator:

```
SELECT CAST(NUM AS varchar(20)) + ';' + CAST(VER AS varchar(20)) AS "MENU" FROM DOCS;
```

The returned result is fine, I get "1;1 or "2;1" etc. but I get warnings on the execution plan:

> Type conversion in expression (CONVERT(varchar(20),[mydb].[dbo].[DOCS].[NUM],0)) may affect "CardinalityEstimate" in query plan choice, Type conversion in expression (CONVERT(varchar(20),[mydb].[dbo].[DOCS].[VER],0)) may affect "CardinalityEstimate" in query plan choice

The example above is a simplified example of a more complex, incredibly busy table and if this is trivial warning, great I'll move on, but I would love to get the "!" to disappear if possible?

Note: I have not observed a performance problem, I am just being proactive (or overly curious and cautious perhaps).

Note2: for clarity, I have added more details about the scenario, such as create table DDL and added some insert statements.

Comment: unable to duplicate the issue, i have created the table as per given info but no warning with me. if you can produce a test case we may help you.

Comment: Is your query overly simplified? Do you have a `WHERE` in your real query? Also, you should get into the habit of declaring the length, scale and precision of your data types. Not doing so can give you some (nasty) surprises.

Comment: UsmanMirza and Lamu: in response to your comments, I have added more details to the original questions. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Personally I suggest to use [computed (virtual) columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017) in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operative word is *may*. This doesn't affect cardinality estimates in this case as the column is just selected and not used in any filtering or grouping operation where this could affect estimates.

There *was* a connect item "New Type Conversion in Expression..... warning in SQL2012 ,too noisy to practical use" in which Microsoft responded

> I see what you mean. While I agree that this is noise in most cases,
>   it is low priority for us to fix. We will look at it if we get more
>   feedback. For now I have closed this by design

This was lost when connect closed down. A similar complaint is on the [UserVoice site here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035/suggestions/32895910).

> it seems to be an overreach when converted/casted columns are simply
>   cited in the selected / projected column list and not at all in
>   filtering clause.

It is possible to jump through some hoops to get rid of it. For example

```
SELECT FORMAT(NUM, 'N0') + ';' + FORMAT(VER, 'N0') 
FROM [DOCS2];
```

But I don't recommend this. `FORMAT` has its own problems (with performance) and applying an unnecessary `FORMAT` makes the code less readable.

Comment: Martin, super. The Microsoft response is what I was looking for. For the time being I'm just going to consider this as noise, but Mark Freeman's reply (on UserVoice site above) reflects my situation pretty well. He says, "This makes it harder to find real problems when practically every plan shows this warning for no good reason." We've been looking at and refactoring some of our code with an eye towards addressing legit warnings and now I have to consider false positives. Anyway, thanks for your time Martin.

Comment: I don't know if it helps but I upvoted the complaint over at https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035/suggestions/32895910