# Unable to fix "may affect "CardinalityEstimate" in query plan choice" conversion warning (int to varchar)

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Hi My task for a project is to remove this warning "Type conversion in expression (CONVERT(varchar(10),[Expr1017],0)) may affect "CardinalityEstimate" in query plan choice". I've been searching for a day and a half how to fix it and most other questions arent exactly what i need (i've tried their solutions but still have it). I can't just ignore it like some answers suggest bc the whole point of my task is to remove it.

`CAST(product.Schedule AS VARCHAR(10)) AS [CSACode],`

the schedule column is NOT computed and is generally either null or a single digit int.

I've tried reducing/increasing the VARCHAR size, using variables to pass around values and then convert that int var to the varchar (another site said issues arise sometime when converting a column to another type), using convert instead of cast, and just rework ton of code so it can return an int save it back in my MVC (it was too much work to do so, my boss said thats not the fix they want, and still resulted in other issues), but nothing seems to remove this warning beyond removing the cast entirely.

Removing this cast doesn't affect the row count at all it just removes the casted column CSACode in my select. I've been googling this CardinalityEstimate and row estimate seems to be all there is to it. It has little to no impact itself from what I can tell .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ay9iw.png)

These 2 are the closest to questions I've found that are similar to my issue but not helpful.
[How to avoid Implicit Type Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62495008/how-to-avoid-implicit-type-conversion)

[Concatenation of INT columns warning: Type conversion in expression causes CardinalityEstimate warnings in execution plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55546183/concatenation-of-int-columns-warning-type-conversion-in-expression-causes-cardi)

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve here? This is a warning in the plan XML that is sometimes relevant, sometimes not - it's a known and often discussed bug/feature that MS is not fixing any time soon, you'll have to live with it.

Comment: All I was told was to get this warning to disappear for my current task. If it's a known bug to appear is there something on an MS site that is tracking it or at least shows it's an official source being a known bug so I can show my boss? Is there a way to search for something like that if it exists?

Comment: you can probably hack it with LEFT(product.Schedule, 10). i'm surprised your boss makes you waste time on casts though, not sure how it will help the company's bottomline or make them leverage the market synergy paradigm shifts etc

Comment: We have a short sprint every year or year and half to fix little issues like warnings/optimization and rewrite code. this was just one they wanted. My understanding was this wasn't really causing any issues since the rest of the SQL code results in identical output with or without this code. It is also barely a few ms faster without it so I'm questioning this as well but was overridden. it's unfortunate bc this is the 1st instance of them wasting time like this.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same error with this minimal example:

```sql
SELECT CAST(product.Schedule AS VARCHAR(10)) AS [CSACode]
FROM (SELECT 123 AS Schedule UNION ALL SELECT NULL) AS product
```

[image]

The warning disappears when I change `CAST(product.Schedule AS VARCHAR(10))` to `FORMAT(product.Schedule, 'N0')`:

```sql
SELECT FORMAT(product.Schedule, 'N0') AS [CSACode]
FROM (SELECT 123 AS Schedule UNION ALL SELECT NULL) AS product
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you I haven't seen this on any related questions or tutorials. I think this could work.

Comment: I would personally not recommend doing this just to remove an *irrelevant* planxml warning - planxml would not even be relevant in production code, `format` is much less performant than `cast` so I suggest to test any changes on suitable datasets.